# How to know what variables and functions are defined by script files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to know what variables and functions are defined by a script file.

I have to use it in scenario where,I'm using cdn to load first,if it fails the variables and functions will not be defined, so i will load the script file from local.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.min.js"></script>

<script>
    if (typeof ($.Core) == 'undefined') {
        // local script source
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: What you have now will work fine. Do you have a specific issue with it?

Comment: Yes,Core is not the variable/function defined in Core.min.js. I gave that in my own assumption

Comment: So you simply need to find a variable that the Core library defines and check it's defined.

Comment: Can you tell me any variable, Please i'm not able to find correct one

Comment: Why not go to the author's github page here: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/tree/master and go through the modules directory to find a function you can check against?

Comment: Thank you @zerohero , what you said worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`$` is the jquery object, so that wouldn't make any sense.

You want to look in the source file at the bottom to see what it defines. This is obviously going to be very hard on a minified file so start by getting the non-minified version. So change the url to be '.js' instead of '.min.js' (and paste that into your browser adress bar to download the non-minified version).
 If you are out of luck and a non-minified version isn't available, try the 'beautifyjs' service.

At the bottom of the file we find

```
// CommonJS export
if(typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports)module.exports = __e;
// RequireJS export
else if(typeof define == 'function' && define.amd)define(function(){return __e});
// Export to global object
else __g.core = __e;
```

We are looking for the `//Export to global object` in this case, and we find they called it `core`

So you want to test for `typeof (core) == 'undefined'`

Comment: And if you want to check all variables/functions, you could use console.log(window);. In your browser-console you can see them all then.